# How to position the styles tab at the bottom of the inspect element workspace?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

The styles tab got positioned horizontally beside the elements tab. How do I get it to the bottom of the element tab as it was by default?
[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrHBr.png)

Answer (score 10):

Click the Settings button (Gear icon) on the top right of the DevTools workspace.

First tab (Preferences) > First list (Appearance) > Set '**Panel layout**' to ***horizontal***

That should do the trick, I hope it works for you as well.